# Prove a Sequence of Functions is Not Uniformly Convergent on [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis

I am given $f_n(x)=\frac{n^2x+e^{nx}-1}{e^{2nx}}$ and have already shown it converges pointwise to $f(x)=0$ on $\Bbb{R}$, moreover that it converges uniformly to $0$ on $[a, \infty)$ for some $a \gt 0$.
Now I am required to show that the function is not uniformly convergent for $x$ in $[0,1]$ but using the uniform norm definition is still giving me the limit is zero, and I cannot find a way to use the epsilon definition with the exponentials in the function.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that $f_n(1/n) \to \infty$